# Bootstrap Popover not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement the bootstrap popover on a website but for some reason it isn't working.

The console does not output any errors and I've also made an alert just to check if the JS was working and it is.

My code is:

**Head**:

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type='text/javascript'>
     $(document).ready(function () {
      alert("Aaaa");
       $('#example').tooltip();
     });
  </script>
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" rel="tooltip" data-placement="right" 
   data-original-title="Tooltip on right"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For performance reasons, the Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt in.
>   If you would like to use them just specify a selector option.

-- [Bootstrap Docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips)

But if you've covered that, it would seem you need to add an id attr to you a tag:

```
<a href="#" rel="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="Tooltip on right">Stuff</a>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/q9qfv/)

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT] try the other answer first.

I think you need to have an id to select in your html to reference in your JS

Also, try it without the type='text/javascript' in the body script.

From

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type='text/javascript'>
     $(document).ready(function () {
      alert("Aaaa");
       $('#example').tooltip();
     });
  </script>
```

to-

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
      alert("Aaaa");
       $('#example').tooltip();
     });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for all elements at same time.

```
$("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();
```